# Missing quotes in Json file

Tags: json, d3.js

I have a very large Json file. It contains 27000 records.

a record looks like this:

```
    {
adlibJSON: {
recordList: {
record: [
{
@attributes: {
priref: "4372",
created: "2011-12-09T23:09:57",
modification: "2012-08-11T17:07:51",
selected: "False"
},
acquisition.date: [
"1954"
],
acquisition.method: [
"bruikleen"
],
association.person: [
"Backer, Bregitta"
],
association.subject: [
"heraldiek"
],
collection: [
"Backer, collectie"
], ... ...
```

The problem is that this is not valid Json. The quotes are missing for the names.

Like for example `acquisition.date` should be `"acquisition.date":`

I need to edit this big json file and add all the quotation marks, otherwise the file doesn't parse with for example D3.js

What is the best way to repair this Json file?

Comment: How many distinct names are there?  Maybe just a Find and Replace in Notepad2 (Or your favorite text editor)?

Comment: I like the RegEx idea then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a decent text editor with regex find and replace capability (e.g., Visual Studio, UltraEdit, etc.).

Then Do: find

`^\s*(\w+\.\w+)\s*:`

and replace with

```
"$1":
```

Or you could use powershell:

```
$allText = gc yourfile.txt
$allText -replace '^\s*(\w+\.\w+)\s*:', '"$1":'
```

Comment: thank you for your help. How should i do this with names with two dots in them? this only selects the names with one dot

Comment: Change to: ^\s*((\w+\.\w+)+)\s*:

Answer (score 0):

If you can open it in a text editor, I think you can simply use a replace function for:

> ```
> ],   -->    ],"
> ```

and

> ```
> : [   -->   ":  [
> ```

If your JSON is formatted the same throughout and doesn't contain those characters, this should work.

--

Note that you'll have to manually edit the first key yourself.

Comment: that is smart, only thing i need to do manually are the ones that are in for example  '@attributes:'